# Mouse behaves normally remotely but not locally

Tags: mouse

If a mouse behaves normally over remote desktop but not for the user physically present, can there be any other explanation other than a hardware fault?

Right click and left click having zero effect in one application on some controls, combobox and grid. They are working normally via teamviewer. No other reports of this from other users of the same application either in the same firm or elsewhere. Computer is Windows 7. I do not have access to the site until tomorrow again and I cannot observe the problem unless there is a user locally in any case.

I was just wondering if the fact that there is no problem on `teamviewer` eliminates all other causes except the local hardware, ie the mouse.
Specifically I am wondering if it eliminates the application itself since `teamviewer` shows that it is capable of receiving the mouse events from Windows.

Comment: please add more details. What is the abnormal behaviour? "If a mouse behaves normally over remote desktop" - what do you mean - mouse pointer works normally when you connect remotely to your pc or your mouse works correctly when you connect to another pc?

Comment: @MátéJuhász, Sorry I added a little more detail.